# Use of jQuery remove() to remove certain children from an element

Tags: jquery

From the documentation, http://api.jquery.com/remove/, it would appear that

```
$('#id').remove('.class');
```

should have the same effect as

```
$('#id').children('.class').remove();
```

However only that the latter works as intended.

Am I doing something wrong or misinterpreting the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the docs.

The selector passed to `.remove()` filters the *set itself*, not any child elements.
In other words, you could write

```
$('#id').children().remove('.class');
```

Or

```
$('#id > *').remove('.class');
```

Comment: Ah I was confused by the docs as the parent and the children in the example are all divs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').children().find('.class').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Try this

Comment: That's _completely_ different.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this question is more about understanding the functionality of the remove() than getting something to work. Don't really need the fadeOut either!